how can I structure a test suite hierarchically
I like ScalaTest, but I'm trying to figure out if I can arrange tests as in the hierarchy below-- where finer-grained tests are dependent upon more coarse-grained tests succeeding-- for the values they produce-- and if those coarser-grained tests fail, don't bother with the finer-grained ones.  For example, I need the parsed PubSub payload before I can parse the message sub-payload, and in turn I need the parsed message sub-payload before I can parse the data sub-sub-payload in the example below.
Is what I am asking for possible with ScalaTest or some other testing framework for Java?

PubSub payload parsed

subscription field matches
message field sub-payload parsed

messageId field matches
publishTime field matches
attributes field contains key/value operation/insert
data field sub-payload parsed

various checks on data








It is probably possible (everything is), but highly unrecommended. Individual tests should be self-contained, and never depend on each other. If you need some common setup for all the tests, you can do that with the before/after aspects. If you need some functionality shared between tests, you can make helper functions. But it is really important, and considered the best practice to be able to (1) run tests in any order (2) be able to run any single test whenever needed, and also highly desired, albeit not always worth the effort is to be able to run multiple tests in parallel
